# Web service Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net, web-services

### I have a problem with a web service. I add a web service reference to my project. I use this service in many pages. It is working correctly, no problems in VS but I copy App_WebReferences folder's files and Web.Config file to ISS path. But it is not working.

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InterkomLaboratuar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 22:     InterkomLaboratuar.Service1SoapClient _sistemTip = new InterkomLaboratuar.Service1SoapClient();

Source File: c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MedulaV3\diyaliz02\Istemler.aspx.cs    Line: 22

---

How can i solve this problem please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy `Bin` folder to `IIS`. You are missing some assemblies.