# IIS ASP.NET Website using a web service compilation error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am having the same exact problem described here:

[Web service Compilation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480899/web-service-compilation-error)

But the answer is not detailed enough for me to try a fix. I cannot find a bin folder.

I connected to a web service using `Add Service Reference` in visual studio. I copied the entire folder to the IIS wwwroot folder including the `App_WebReferences` folder which was automatically added when adding the service reference.

Running the site right from visual studio works great.

Any help would be great. I'm using IIS 7.5.

UPDATE to show error:

FlightWS is the reference name I gave to the service when I connected it using the 'Add Service Reference' and pasted in the url of the `wsdl` file.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this     request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code     appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FlightWS' could not be found (are you     missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 13:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 14:     {
Line 15:         FlightWS.AccountType user = (FlightWS.AccountType)Session["user"];
Line 16:         if (user != null && !user.Equals(null))
Line 17:         {

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ServiceClient\Index.aspx.cs    Line: 15 


Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

Comment: pate your error here.

Comment: You said you cannot find bin folder is it right?

Comment: Correct. Do I need to publish the site?

Comment: If it is web project than yes publish it and check.

Comment: Just published. Gave me the same files as I have in the folder and still did not work. No bin folder created and no compiled pages.

Comment: Ok try to add bin folder from VS and then into website folder in IIS.If folder already there VS will prompt you than open folder in explorer and you may see bin folder.